# SQL Query for Selecting multiple rows with multiple column value

Tags: sql, string, db2, where-clause, sql-in

I want to do the following in the db2 SQL

```
select * from table where column =(value1,value2,value3)
```

result should return all the rows with all columns for the given table whose column values is value1,value2 and value3

Answer (score 2):

Do you want `in`?

```
select * from mytable where mycol in ('value1', 'value2' ,'value3')
```

This returns entire rows of `mytable` for which `mycol` has one of the three literal values enumerated on the right side of the `in` operator.